# Add VS 2008 menu item

Tags: visual-studio-2008

When I open a WPF project and right click in the solution explorer there is a sub menu item where you can add WPF specific items (Add UserControl, Window, Page, ResourceDictionary, etc.)

How can I add a template that I created to that menu? Is it possible or simply a waste of time. I can simply click "New Item" and then find it.

Just wondering.

Answer (score 2):

You need to customize the toolbars. Specifically, the "Context Menus" toolbar.

1. Select "Customize..." from the "Tools" menu to display the "Customize" dialog.
2. Select the "Toolbars" tab.
3. Check the "Context Menus" item.
4. Modify the context menu you need.

You will probably have to create a macro to open the specific item, then "drag" this macro to the context menu. Macros can be found on the "Commands" tab. Select the "Macros" category to display all the available macros in the "Commands" list box.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=How+to%3A+Customize+Toolbars+%28Visual+Studio%29&ac=8

Answer (score 0):

http://www.carlosag.net/Articles/createVSTemplate.aspx

Comment: not what I needed, it doesn't tell me how to add menu items to the context menu